# Is there a way to alert an external workbook user through vba?

Tags: vba, excel

We have excel files that we use as databases for various parts of our operations. We also have "manipulator" files that write to the "database" files.

The problem is that multiple users can be working in the manipulator files and trying to write to the databases at the same time, which can create syncing issues.

For example, one manipulator file pulls in data from a database, the user makes some updates, then the manipulator vba logs the new information to the respective database. If the database was updated during that time by another user, there is a risk of corrupting our database.

Is there anyway I can alert the external workbook user if their data is out of sync? Or is there another way we can avoid "out of sync" issues?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Open the database book whenever someone is in a manipulator book? That forces it into read only for everyone else.

Comment: This is a potential problem for *any* database system.  One approach is to put a timestamp on each row so it can be checked before overwriting someone else's changes.  It does create more complexity, but the alternative is only allowing one editor at a time.

Comment: You may want to use **Share Workbook** feature right from Excel:  **Review** tab, **Changes** group, you can also restrict edits to ranges for different people, track changes (option to accept/reject) as well.

Comment: Sound like your work flow is fundimentally flawed.  IMHO you would best revisit the whol;e design, probably migrating to a real DB

Comment: I agree with Chris Nielsen. But in the interim, maybe put the files on a SharePoint site where the files need to be checked out so they are read only until checked in.

Comment: Can you mimic the access lock file in some way, so a text file is updated with environ("UserName") which gives a list of users in the sheet, this will be done in the "database" workbook_open.  This can then be checked by the "updater" and either from there find a way of alerting the user, NETSEND poss :) if not a timer in the "database" can check a text file from the "updater" saying its trying to update and then alert the user using messagebox.  I agree with all that a properly thought about shared WB/Sharepoint or DB would be your best option.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the suggestions.

We don't have huge scale at this time, therefore I think we'll make do with this for the time being. 

@Nathan_Sav, thanks for the suggestion on putting an timer in the db file. Just to confirm, are you suggesting that the db check a third file which is updated by updaters when they're accessing the db, and use that to alert the users if more than one are in the db?

Answer (score 0):

We decided that for now we will continue with the current setup and handle conflicts if they arise. We will, however, migrate to a thought-out DB as soon as possible.

Thanks for all the suggestions!